# trying to close dropdown menu when dropdown menu is open and user clicks document

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to hide my dropdown menu when the user clicks outside of its open state, Im using a flag `isActive` that determines whether or not the menu is open and then I have added a click event on the document to hide the menu if open and stop propogation on the menu if it is clicked. Right now however when I click my dropdown anchor tag the document click event is fired. Can anyone advise how I fix this?

JS

```
//User profile share tooltip
        $('.btn-social-share').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

                if( !isActive ){
                    $('.social-share-options').show();
                    isActive = true;
                } else {
                    $('.social-share-options').hide();
                    isActive = false;
                }

        });

        /* Anything that gets to the document
           will hide the dropdown */
        $(document).on('click', function(){
            if( isActive ){
                $('.social-share-options').hide();
                isActive = false;
            }
        });

        /* Clicks within the dropdown won't make
           it past the dropdown itself */
        $('.social-share-options').click(function(e){
          e.stopPropagation();
        });
```

Comment: Can you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Your code should work, which makes me think that maybe another element is receiving the click, have you tried doing a console.log in your click event handler for .social-share-options? This could tell you if .social-share-options is actually receiving the click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a condition that checks if whatever was clicked is within the dropdown or not, and then hide the dropdown if whatever was clicked is not within the dropdown :

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
    if( isActive && $(e.target).closest('.social-share-options').length === 0 ){
        $('.social-share-options').removeClass('is-active');
        isActive = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is one solution, but doesn't necessarily give you a solution to your original problem. Your code should work, but I think there's probably some other element receiving the click. That said this is a totally viable solution either way!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it but I think you need to add `e.stopPropagation()`, that will prevent your event from bubbling up :

```
  $('.btn-social-share').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        //...
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/